# How do I install mogul light fixtures?

Tags: light-fixture

Suppose I want to install mogul light fixture on my garage ceiling.

- Can I simply connect the wires of the existing standard housing to mogul socket? Example: https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/171742/CL-10008.html
- Are there any additional elements that I need to add to the circuit?
- Does it matter if I'll be using actual HID lamps vs. "HID-replacement" (LEDs with a mogul socket)?
- Does the light need to be put some distance away from the ceiling (ie. hung like bay lights) to allow heat to dissipate, or is having it right up to the ceiling okay?

Comment: What does the data sheet / instructions say about heat and spacing?

Comment: @SolarMike I have no idea. If I could find one, I wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: Heat issues depend on the lamp type more than (or at least, along with) the socket. So find the light bulb you want to use and see what the specs there say about distance from insulation, distance from ceiling, etc.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Well, here's one: https://www.mcmaster.com/8352K55/ it doesn't say anything about how to install it. That one says it's equivalent to a bulb from Sylvania LU250, which is widely available, but the most I could find is a one-page generic sheet on some sites. Sylvania doesn't even have it on their site.

Comment: They do have https://www.sylvania-lighting.com/product/en-gb/products/0020843/ but none of the documents given for it (including the "data sheet" and "technical datasheet") explain how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

The Mcmaster product says it needs an ANSI S50 ballast to operate, I don't know about the other non-UL lamp that is made by an 80% Chinese company/20% German owned company marketing UK products.

An S50 ballast needs to be in a fixture housing or enclosure and needs to be wired per the diagram on the ballast or [instructions included with the ballast](https://a89b8e4143ca50438f09-7c1706ba3fabeeda794725d88e4f5e57.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/spec_sheets/files/000/003/935/original/advance-71a8251001d-specs.pdf?1440178149).

This Mcmaster bulb is an odd choice, it's 2100k light output color is like old yellow parking lot bulb.

An LED product would depend on the specific product, some require a ballast, some require bypassing ballast.

Comment: The McMaster bulb is indeed marketed for parking lots. It's just an example. I assume all HIDs require such ballast regardless of color temp, or is that not the case? Anyway, I see now how you figure out that you need a ballast. It also says that the ballast must be 2ft away from the lamp. But I'm still confused by this. Is the capacitor and ignitor part of the ballast, or are they wire separately?

Comment: Also, why do you mention the company being 80% Chinese/20% German? Do these countries use a different light bulb design? It seems like all countries generally use about the same general style of light and market it globally. What is the significance of the country affiliation?

Comment: Different countries use different standards, voltages, and frequencies. German and Chinese (as well as the UK market the Sylvania product is actually intended for) equipment are both likely to expect 230V 50Hz, not the 120V 60Hz you find in the US - although a lot of US high-power commercial light fittings (like HIDs) might be 120 or 277, or 277 only.

Comment: The cap and ignitor are seprate components that in the US are typically sold in the US in a ballast kit. I don't know that US lighting operating standards are the same as Euro-Asia electrical standards. I do know some differences. The EU Sylvania bulb shown is "CE" self certified, where US requires independent certification (UL,CSA,ETL) and the socket is E40 (Edison 40mm) rather than E39 that the North American version Sylvania LU250 uses. Is this socket different to prevent cross installation? I also in 35 years installing bulbs I never saw HPS glass shaped in ED28 form rather than T14.5.

Comment: The 2' distance for the capacitor is a maximum distance, typically the ballast kit components come with 6" or less wire leads that can be used in factory designed fixtures without trimming or extending. A larger cap is typically required to be calculated for remote or ballast bank configuration.